# Providing permissions to access artifacts in one pipeline using a job from another pipeline

Tags: jenkins, permissions, jenkins-pipeline

I have two pipelines: pipeline A and pipeline B. Pipeline B has a job that requires me to read an artifact (a csv file) from pipeline A. I have added code into my script in pipeline B to grab and read this csv, but I am unable to access the file. How do I provide pipeline B with elevated perms to access pipeline A?

Comment: Firstly, do you ensure both pipelines always run on same Jenkins agent, otherwise it's challenge to access a file on another machine.

Comment: What is the exact error you get when you try to access the file?

Comment: So the way I obtain the file is with curl [url of jenkins artifact which is a csv file], and then when I do cat index.csv i get “Authentication required”

Comment: If by jenkins agent you mean the build executor then yeah it’s different executors sadly